# How can I export a variable from one file and require() the exported variable on another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

my folder structure :

```
collegesapp --

             |-- node_modules -- express
             |                -- connect
             |                -- jade
             |                -- passport
             |-- routes -- routes.js
             |-- views   -- index.jade
             |           -- signin.jade
             |-- app.js
             |-- package.json

exports.serialized_user = "Alex"; //in app.js file

var serialized_user = require('../app.js').serialized_user; //in routes.js file
```

So, when I add `console.log(serialized_user )` to my `routes.js` file and run the application, I end up having seeing undefined in console instead of "Alex". What do you think is my problem?

Answer (score 3):

in app.js file, use

```
module.exports.serialized_user = "Alex";
```

or

```
module.exports={serialized_user: "Alex"};
```

instead of

```
exports.serialized_user = "Alex";
```